# Merge all.x=T introduces NA's

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

My data looks like this simplified (shortened) sample data:

```
old <- data.frame(nr=c(4551, 4001, 301, 4271, 321, 4221, 261), name=c("Aadorf", "Aarau", "Aarberg", "Aarburg", "Aarwangen", "Abtwil", "Zollikon"), nr=c(26.3, 38.4, 30.8, 34.7, 31.0, 20.5, 31.5))
new <- data.frame(nr=c(4560, 4001,  301, 4271,  321, 4221), nr=c(46.65, 56.64, 57.62, 55.33, 61.62, 35.77))
```

Now I want to merge the two `data.frames` by it's numbers:

```
both <- merge(old, new, all.x=T, by="nr")
```

This works, but when I have a look at the output I loose some of the names of `old`:

```
> both
       nr      name    nr.1.x  nr.1.y
  [1]  301   Aarberg   30.8    57.62
  [2]  321 Aarwangen   31.0    61.62
  [3] 4001     Aarau   38.4    56.64
  [4] 4221    Abtwil   20.5    35.77
  [5] 4271   Aarburg   34.7    55.33
  [6] 4551    Aadorf   26.3    NA
  [7]  261        NA   31.5    NA
```

I don't understand why it introduces `NA` instead of the name in the seventh row. If I run my example, I don't have that problem (I guess it's because the numbers are too small), but it should illustrate what I'm struggling with. When I have a look at my data it seems pretty random where R introduces `NA` and where not.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here's the original data:
[New](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7r15hcs3e6h83f/new.csv?dl=0)
[Old](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf871telj180l2g/old.csv?dl=0)

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.. Running `merge(old, new, by= "nr", all.x=T)` gives me all 7 `name` entries from `old` (no NAs in `name` column)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's more of an illustration, because my dataset is too large to be posted here. As stated, it works for me too (therefore a bad example to reproduce my problem). I hoped that someone stumbled over this as well.

Comment: Try to make your problem reproducible - either you'll find out why this seems to happen while you create a minimal example, or if not, someone will be able to help you. But as it's currently described, it's not clear what you mean because what you describe is not the normal behavior of `merge()`.

Comment: Well, I am aware of that. I uploaded the two files and "hope" that you have the same problem as I do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not omit by='nr':

```
> merge(new, old, all=T)
     nr  nr.1      name
1   261 31.50  Zollikon
2   301 30.80   Aarberg
3   301 57.62      <NA>
4   321 31.00 Aarwangen
5   321 61.62      <NA>
6  4001 38.40     Aarau
7  4001 56.64      <NA>
8  4221 20.50    Abtwil
9  4221 35.77      <NA>
10 4271 34.70   Aarburg
11 4271 55.33      <NA>
12 4551 26.30    Aadorf
13 4560 46.65      <NA>
```